# Does Hibernate `Session` has a method called `find()` which takes a HQL string?

Tags: java, hibernate

From Database System Concepts 6ed

> To retrieve students, we can use the following code snippet
>
> ```
> Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
> Transaction txn = session.beginTransaction();
> List students =
> session.ﬁnd("from Student as s order by s.ID asc");
> for ( Iterator iter = students.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
> Student stud = (Student) iter.next();
> .. print out the Student information ..
> }
> txn.commit();
> session.close();
> ```
>
> The above code snippet uses a query in Hibernate’s HQL query language.
>   The HQL query is automatically translated to SQL by Hibernate and
>   executed, and the results are converted into a list of Student
>   objects. The for loop iterates over the objects in this list and
>   prints them out.

I googled and don't find `Session` has a method called `find()` which takes a HQL string. Is it deprecated or am I missing it?  I am not sure what Hibernate version the book uses. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method was replaced in favor of `createQuery` since Hibernate 4.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/classic/Session.html
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html